# JQueryUI autocomplete: отслеживать процесс выбора элемента

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Использую Autocomplete у jQueryUI. [Вот мой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/9xu9Z/2/)

Сделал, чтобы при вводе текста в фильтр, выводилась 1-ая удовлетворяющая запись.

Когда идет выбор элемента с помощью стрелок(или мышкой проводя по списку) - текст в input меняется, и в списке показывается временное выделение. **Как можно перехватиь событие выбора через стрелки (или проводя мышкой по списку)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю в данном случае нужно работать с событием `focus`. Только нужно использовать `event.preventDefault()`

Пример

```
$( "#element" ).autocomplete({
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.item.label);
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kison/7VKRz/)

Comment: подозревал что это свойство для этого нужно.., но у меня не получалось с ним ) пойду смотреть возможные проблемы :)